# How can i save a user's input on api.ai(dialogflow)?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

Basically i want the user to forward an input and I want that input to be saved by the chatbot and used, for example:

```
human:hi
bot:hello
human:take the input first input
bot:First input has been added anything else
```

what i did at first is created an entity and added many input values for testing purposes only but my bot should basically take any input and store it for later use in the conversation. I also looked into `@sys.given-name` but won't work for my case as the input won't be a human name.It could be `ajdhshdj` as far as i'm concerned and i'd want to take it.

Comment: can you explain more Jimmy. api ai is not save user input data.you have to do in your side.

Comment: Sure Manjeet, i want the bot to be able to take an input from the user without that input being pre-set as an element of an entity let's say i want to save a user's feedback on my product it could be something like : it was great or nice service or even some nonesense like ygwyegwe7 , however, no matter what i want to take his exact input and use it later in the conversation as well.

Comment: you means `it was great ` or `nice service` , `ygwyegwe7` these values you want to capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want the `@sys.any` entity for your parameter. Use this sparingly, and in low-priority intents if you must, but it should match "anything".

If there are other components of what they're saying that you don't want to capture, you can just highlight the part in your sample phrase you want as a parameter and set the type to `@sys.any`. So you might have something like this:

[image]

Comment: And how can i make the bot know that he should take that part if it's a long sentence.

Comment: Updated answer to clarify a little

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but let's say I want to set a football match date, and my input is the match will be called superb match and will be played tomorrow at 4 pm between Arsenal and Chelsea. I want the bot to directly recognized match name as superb match without these exact two words being trained or highlighted like your example, how can i make my bot "smarter".

Comment: I'm now confused what you're actually trying to do. Please update your original question to clarify. You originally said "It could be ajdhshdj as far as i'm concerned and i'd want to take it." and now you're saying that you want to match something more specific.

Comment: (Or post it as a new question, since it seems like this answered your original question, and you accepted it, and now you're asking something new.)